# How to get a URL segment

Tags: segments

I can see that `craft.request.firstSegment` and `craft.request.lastSegment` works but `craft.request.secondSegment` does not. Is there a way (as in ExpressionEngine) to get the value of any URL segment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Craft 2: `craft.request.getSegment(2)`, see [Craft docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/craft.request.html#getsegment-n)

Craft 3: `craft.app.request.getSegment(2)`

Answer (score 6):

There's also another way that would be more consistent, in case your segments are **not always** in the same segments array **position**.
You'd make your routes to match a certain mask in the **routes.php** file like so:

```
return [
  '<country_code:[a-z]{2}(-[a-z]{2})?>/<section_URI:team>' => ['template' => 'team']
];
```

And then in your **twig** template you could access the variables `country_code` and `section_URI` as long as these two were provided in the URL, otherwise they'll be undefined, which you can also check.

```
{% if country_code is defined %}
   //Do something with country_code
{% endif %}
```

**Note:** The syntax used in Craft 3 routing differs from the one in Craft 2: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#url-rules